# Function of a matrix operator in $L^2(\mathbb R)\otimes\mathbb C^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider an operator $A:=\left(\begin{matrix}A_{11} & A_{12}\\A_{21} & A_{22}\end{matrix}\right)$, where each $A_{ij}$, $i,j=1,2$ is a bounded self-adjoint linear operator in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.
Suppose that $f$ is a function defined in $\mathbb R$ such that each operator $f(A_{ij})$ is well-defined.
Is it possible to relate $f(A)$ to the $f(A_{ij})$?

Comment: For $H=L^2(\Bbb{R})$, what's the action of $A$ on $H\otimes H$?  It looks like an operator on $H\oplus H$.

Comment: @JohnDoe: thanks for pointing it out. I'm considering a system of spin-1/2 particles on the real line, which is described by a pair $(\psi_1,\psi_2)$ with $\psi_1,\psi_2\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Therefore the operator $A$ is defined in the the space $L^2(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{C}^2)$ of square-summable functions with values in $\mathbb{C}^2$, which is isomorphic to $L^2(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathbb{C}^2$. I fixed the title accordingly.